# SVN GUI frontends for managing projects and users?

Tags: svn, unix, trac, administration

Our hackerspace (091labs.com) is getting a few software projects started at the moment, and we're using Trac and SVN for bug tracking/source control.

However, every time I set up a new projects I've to go through the whole speil in the command line of creating the Trac project, creating the SVN repository, configuring auth, editing config files to add users etc.

Is there any GUIs (preferably web based) that you could recommend that would allow me to set up different projects and repositories easily with user management support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that VisualSVN client can be used with any svn server, not just the VisualSVN server.

Answer (score 2):

try visualsvn - http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: Thanks, running a windows server in a hackerspace is somewhat of a taboo though :)

Comment: sorry i didnt see in the question that your platform should not be a windows platform